# How does magic_enum library can output enum value as string with msvc?

Tags: c++, reflection, enums

The [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) library provides way to retrieve an enum value as its name, in the form of a string.
For instance:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "magic_enum.hpp"

enum class Dummy : uint16_t {
    first,
    second,
    third,
};

int main() {
    std::cout << magic_enum::enum_name<Dummy::first>()
              << std::endl;  // outputs "first"}
```

Does some can explain here how `magic_enum` actually implements `enum_name` with msvc?

I managed to reproduce this behavior with clang/gcc by passing the enum value to a template function and using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` inside, for instance:

```cpp
template<typename Enum_T, Enum_T Value_E> class EnumValueNameAsString
{
    static constexpr std::string_view Get()
    {
        auto constexpr end = std::string_view(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__).find_last_of(';');
        if constexpr (end == std::string_view::npos)
        {
            return std::string_view("Failure");
        }
        auto constexpr start
            = std::string_view(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__).find_last_of('=', end);
        if constexpr (start == std::string_view::npos)
        {
            return std::string_view(
                "Failure");
        }
        // 0 <= start < end
        if constexpr (end - start <= 2)
        {
            return std::string_view(
                "Failure");
        }
        return std::string_view(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__).substr(start + 2, end - start - 2);
    }

public:
    static constexpr std::string_view Name = Get();
};
```

But for C++, using `__FUNCSIG__` instead of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, I cannot achieve the expected result as `__FUNCSIG__` actually is `class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > __cdecl EnumValueNameAsString<enum Dummy,0>::Get(void)`
The enum value name is nowhere in the string.

Comment: did you look at the code https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum ?

Comment: Yes I did but I'm lost. I don't know what path my compiler actually choose among all the #define
By the way, it's by looking at the source that I got the Idea of the ```Get``` function in my question.

Comment: fwiw the standard macro is `__func__`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ```__func__``` provides me only ```Get```

Comment: "I don't know what path my compiler actually choose among all the #define" => You can ask MSVC to output the result of the pre-compiler. That will resolve every conditional for you and show you what *actually* gets passed on to the compilation step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `__FUNCSIG__` only converts an enum non-type template argument to its name in the immediately enclosing function. It will leave the `0` in the struct as a `0` since that's not the function being called.

The fix is to use the enum template argument in the static member function, or use a free function:

```cpp
template<typename Enum_T, Enum_T Value_E>
constexpr std::string_view f() { return __FUNCSIG__; }

template<typename Enum_T, Enum_T Value_E>
class EnumValueNameAsString {
    template<Enum_T>
    static constexpr std::string_view Get() {
        return __FUNCSIG__;
    }
public:
    static constexpr std::string_view Name = Get<Value_E>();
};

static_assert(f<Dummy, Dummy::first>() ==
"class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > __cdecl f<enum Dummy,Dummy::first>(void)"
);

static_assert(EnumValueNameAsString <Dummy, Dummy::first>::Name ==
"class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > __cdecl EnumValueNameAsString<enum Dummy,0>::Get<Dummy::first>(void)"
);
```